# Uniquely defined autoregression

Tags: time-series, autoregressive

Let $\{w_t\}, t \in \mathbb{Z}$ be a random noise. Given a sequence $\{w_t\}$, does the autoregression

$x_t = x_{t-1} - 0.9 x_{t-2} + w_t$,  $ t \in \mathbb{Z}$

uniquely define a sequence $\{x_t\}$?

If not, is it enough to impose the value of the mean of $\{x_t\}$ to make this sequence uniquely defined?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "fixing" the $w_i$? That sounds like you are specifying a sequence of *numbers,* but in that case could you explain what sense an expectation might make?  And if you intend the $w_i$ to be a stochastic process itself, then please tell us what you mean by "uniquely defined."

Comment: @whuber, thank you, it wasn't clear indeed. Please let me know if the question is good now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a two-term recursion.  Given *arbitrary* values for $x_0$ and $x_1,$ the formula

$$x_t = x_{t-1} -0.9 x_{t-2} + w_t$$

recursively determines $x_2, x_3, \ldots, x_n, \ldots$ and the inverse formula (found by solving this one for $x_{t-2}$ with $s=2-t$)

$$x_{-s} = \frac{-x_{2-s} + x_{1-s} + w_{2-s}}{0.9}$$

recursively determines $x_{-1}, x_{-2}, \ldots, x_{-n}, \ldots.$

Both recursions make sense whether the $x_t$ and $w_t$ are interpreted as sequences of random variables or just sequences of numbers.

Note that since each formula expresses $x_t$ or $x_{-s}$ as a Real linear combination of the preceding $x$'s and $w$'s, it follows by induction that *all* terms in the sequence are real linear combinations of $x_0, x_1,$ and the $w$'s.  If you are thinking of these objects as numbers, with the $w$'s given, this shows that **the set of all such sequences is a two-dimensional vector space.**

In particular, imposing a single linear constraint on these sequences will yield a one-dimensional vector space.  Thus, the analog for random variables--such as fixing the means--still will not determine the sequence uniquely.

The generalization to longer-term recursions (AR$(k)$ models) should be clear.